# App force closing if sqlite record goes above 5

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on a building directory app, and when doing an address reverse lookup, the code will work fine for the first 5 records, but crash with an error of

> 'android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0'

I've logged the number of records, and the column index. The first 5 records in the table produce the expected results, however, anything above that in the index count, it crashes.

Heres the code for the activity:

```
public class AddressReverse extends Activity implements TextWatcher 
{
AutoCompleteTextView actv;
String address[];
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.address_reverse);

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT address FROM buildings", null);

    if (c!=null)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
                results.add(address);
                Log.d("Cursor count", c.getCount()+"");
                Log.d("Cursor Index", c.getColumnIndex("address")+"");
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    actv.addTextChangedListener(this);
    actv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, results));

    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String address = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuildingDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("building", address);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

EDIT: Heres a logcat of the crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dynamite.bible/com.dynamite.bible.BuildingDetails}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at com.dynamite.bible.BuildingDetails.onCreate(BuildingDetails.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8952):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  618):   Force finishing activity com.dynamite.bible/.BuildingDetails
W/ActivityManager(  618):   Force finishing activity com.dynamite.bible/.AddressReverse
```

Comment: from what exception you have posted, it does not look like , it works for first 5 items. The exception is clear that , cursor has 0 items, though looking at your code, this error should not have come, since all error checking is done. So do post the whole exception stack

Comment: ok after doing some digging, i i found what the problem was. when inputting the address, the address of the building was the name of the building, and the BuildingDetails activity sql statement was iterating through the name column instead of the address column. i made a new activity with the same code (except to iterate through the address column) and everything is all good in the hood. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you close the cursor!
Try instead to let the Activity manage your cursor by adding

```
startManagingCursor(c);
```

to your `onCreate()` method.